# Difference between  Fusion Charts and  sencha touch charts?

Tags: iphone, ipad, sencha-touch, fusioncharts

What is the difference between sencha and Fusion charts when we use in Mobile Browsers(iphone,ipad,blackberry)?What are the advantages and disadvantages of them?

Answer (score 2):

FusionCharts v3.2 and later, leverages both Flash and JavaScript (HTML5) to create stunning data visualizations. It works with both XML and JSON data and can be integrated with any server-side technology (ASP, ASP.NET, PHP, JSP, ColdFusion and Ruby on Rails etc.) and database.

Whereas, Sencha is the world’s first purely HTML5-based, mobile charting and drawing product. allows you to develop mobile web apps that look and feel native on iPhone, Android, and BlackBerry touch devices but it does not support Flash.

In FusionCharts, the charts can be rendered on devices like iPhone/iPad using the in-built JavaScript rendering capabilities, powered by Highcharts library. It gives the option of either using automatic fallback, wherein the charts figure out the best mode of rendering (either Flash or JavaScript, based on availability of Flash Player), or lets you configure whether to render charts exclusively using JavaScript.

Flash Player is currently available for Andorid (2.2), where the FusionCharts Flash based charts will automatically be enabled but JavaScript charts would not be supported, as of now.
In the further advanced versions, both Flash and JavaScript charts would be supported.

FusionCharts currently supports the rendering of only the JavaScript (HTML5) charts on BlackBerry OS 6+. But, Flash version of FusionCharts isn't supported on BlackBerry devices, as of now.

Comment: Does that mean Fusion charts internally falls back to using the free highcharts library on iPhone? In that case why not use highcharts directly instead for paying for fusion charts bundle (assuming one is satisfied with the selection offered by highcharts)